# Using $(this) in custom function and .ready(function(){})

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I  got some problems about using `$(this)` in a function which is able to get element `font-size`.

Here i tried 3 statements but only statement 1 works.

Since I didn't use the function "adjust_size" in statement 1, It's actually not what i want but just a try, I want to know what's wrong with statement 2 & 3 .

```js
function adjust_size(){
 alert($(this).css('font-size'));
}
/*---------------statment 1-----------------*/
$(function(){
 $('.a').click(function(){
  alert($(this).css('font-size'));
 })
})
/*---------------statment 2-----------------*/
$(function(){
 $('.b').click(function(){
  adjust_size();
 })
})
/*---------------statment 3-----------------*/
$(function(){
 $('.c').ready(function(){
  alert($(this).css('font-size'));
 })
})
```

```css
.a{
font-size:10vw;
color:blue;
}
.b{
font-size:10vw;
color:red;
}
.c{
font-size:10vw;
color:green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="a">hi there :D</div>
<div class="b">hi there :D</div>
<div class="c">hi there :D</div>
```

Comment: You need to do more *basic* reading.  **B** doesn't work because you don't understand `this` and **C** doesn't work because you don't understand `ready()`.

Comment: you are right :( , I learn this all by self-learning. and I am still not very good at basic stuffs.

Answer (score 3):

For statement 2, you need to pass `this` to the function :

```
function adjust_size(t){
    alert($(t).css('font-size'));
}

$(function(){
    $('.b').click(function(){
        adjust_size(this);
    })
})
```

For statement 3, the DOM is already `ready()` when the function is declared so the event `ready` you put on `$('.c')` gets never called.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your `this` in adjust_size refer to adjust_size, and not to the element calling the function. 
In other word, you have to do this :

```
function adjust_size(elem){
  alert($(elem).css('font-size'));
}

$(function(){
  $('.b').click(function(){
      adjust_size(this);
  })
})
```

Answer (score 2):

In your second example, `this` is not the same in your event handler and in the `adjust_size` function. You can either explicitly bind it:

```
$('.b').click(function() {
   adjust_size.call(this);
});
```

or just let it bind itself:

```
$('.b').click(adjust_size);
```

In your third example, you misuse `$.ready()`. It's not very clear in the [docs](https://api.jquery.com/ready/), but inside the callback, `this` will not refer to `.c`, but to `document`. You need to explicitly select it again:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  alert($('.c').css('font-size'));
});
```

**Full demo**

```js
function adjust_size() {
  alert($(this).css('font-size'));
}
/*---------------statment 1-----------------*/
$('.a').click(function() {
  alert($(this).css('font-size'));
});
/*---------------statment 2-----------------*/
$('.b').click(adjust_size);
/*---------------statment 3-----------------*/
$(document).ready(function() {
  alert($('.c').css('font-size'));
});
```

```css
div{font-size:6vw;color:#00f}.b{color:red}.c{color:green}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="a">hi there :D</div>
<div class="b">hi there :D</div>
<div class="c">hi there :D</div>
```